# How to find out cfm of a kitchen exhaust to be replaced?

Tags: kitchens

The manufacturer of the current kitchen exhaust I'm looking to replace has gone belly up for a long time. I'm struggling to find out from the labels on its cfm stats. How would you suggest finding this information, or is it irrelevant (when I can calculate the cfm I need)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not *too* relevant. What information do you have - brand, model, physical size, any power-related markings on the fan/motor, etc.?

Comment: Model number, measured physical size, re: the fan/motor, I would have to take the cover off to find out the information?

Comment: Depends on the particular appliance. Sometimes model #s are prominently displayed, sometimes on a hidden label, sometimes not at all. Motor/power specs can be a number of different places. No simple answer.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on the model number given the company went belly up already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother attempting to determine the existing rating, if for no other reason that it may not have been properly sized to begin with, and / or recommendations may have changed since then. Previous appliances may have been replaced or updated, or additional appliances may have been added. If it's a commercial kitchen there are likely to be applicable codes that may also have been changed since the original installation.

Better to start with the manufacturer(s) of the exhaust fan you are contemplating installing, and use their calculations. Most of them have online calculators that take into account the kitchen's volume, cooking appliance BTU, ducting considerations... etc.